# Proof explanation required

Tags: proof-explanation

Could someone explain or comment the proof **X** from my lecture notes?

We have been given:

- $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$
- $A^+$ a Moore-Penrose-Inverse
- $V$ some unitary space
- $b \in \mathbb{C}^m$
- a system of linear equations $Ax=b$
- the theorem **Y** that says:

> $\varphi: V \to V$ with $\varphi^2=\varphi$ is a self-adjoint operator
>   $\Leftrightarrow \ \forall u \in Im(\varphi) \land \forall w \in
> Ker(\varphi): \langle u,w \rangle = 0$. In this case we call $\varphi$
>   an orthogonal projection.

- the theorem **Z** that says:

> if $\varphi$ is an orthogonal projection, then for all $v \in V:
>  \varphi(v)$ is a unique vector from $Im(\varphi)$ that has the minimal
>   distance to $v$.

We want to show:

- for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n: \Vert Ax-b \Vert \ge \Vert AA^+b-b \Vert$

The proof **X**:

> As $AA^+AA^+=AA^+$ and as $AA^+$ is a hermitian matrix, $AA^+$ defines
>   an orthogonal projection according to the theorem **Y**. It is
>   $$Im(\varphi) \subseteq \{Ax \mid x \in \mathbb{C}^n\}$$ and for $Ax
>  \in U$: $$Ax=AA^+Ax=\varphi(Ax) \in Im(\varphi).$$ So $\varphi$ is an
>   orthogonal projection on $Im(\varphi)$, and the theorem **Z** implies
>   the assertion.

1. What does "*$AA^+$ defines a map*" mean?
2. What does it mean, "$AA^+$ defines a projection *according to* **Y**"? **Y** says something different, what we do according to it?
3. What is $\{ Ax \mid x \in \mathbb{C}^n\}$? If this should be a set of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^m$, why do we write it this way? We have just said that we work with $AA^+$, why do we multiply $x$ with $A$ and construct some set?
4. Why $Im(\varphi) \subseteq \{Ax \mid x \in \mathbb{C}^n\}$?
5. Why $\varphi(Ax) \in Im(\varphi)$?
6. How these two equalities imply that $\varphi$ is an orthogonal projection on $Im(\varphi)$? Was it not that we assumed in the beginning?
7. How theorem **Z** implies the inequality?